# ValueError: Cannot run multiple SparkContexts at once in spark with pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

i am new in using spark , i try to run this code on pyspark

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
import collections

conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("RatingsHistogram")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
```

but he till me this erore message

```
Using Python version 3.5.2 (default, Jul  5 2016 11:41:13)
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
>>> from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
>>> import collections
>>> conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("RatingsHistogram")
>>> sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)



   Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\spark\python\pyspark\context.py", line 115, in __init__
        SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
      File "C:\spark\python\pyspark\context.py", line 275, in _ensure_initialized
        callsite.function, callsite.file, callsite.linenum))
    ValueError: Cannot run multiple SparkContexts at once; existing SparkContext(app=PySparkShell, master=local[*]) created by getOrCreate at C:\spark\bin\..\python\pyspark\shell.py:43
    >>>
```

i have version spark 2.1.1 and python 3.5.2 , i search and found it is problem in sc ,he could not read it but no when till why , any one have help here

Comment: You are using your code inside of pyspark2, which creates a SparkSession for you already. Don't use pyspark shell since you are creating your own SparkContext. Save your code into a Python file and submit it via `spark-submit`

Comment: @arun Post it as an answer

Comment: it run in win shell, but not run in jupyter notebook or canopy , at all i will find the problem , thank you a lot @arun

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You can try out this

`sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate();`

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 27):

You can try:

```
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf=conf)
```

Answer (score 8):

Your previous session is still on. You can run

```html
sc.stop()
```

Answer (score 0):

it can run through Jupyter lab also. but you have to use as your previous session is still running and local can not run two sessions at a time
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate( conf =conf)