# Unable to create spark session

Tags: python, apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

> When I am creating a spark session, it is throwing an error

- Unable to create a spark session
- Using `pyspark`, the code snippet:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-2262882856df> in <module>()
     37 if __name__ == "__main__":
     38     conf = SparkConf()
---> 39     sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
     40 #     print(sc.version)
     41 #     sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyspark/context.py in __init__(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, gateway, jsc, profiler_cls)
    131                     " note this option will be removed in Spark 3.0")
    132 
--> 133         SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
    134         try:
    135             self._do_init(master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer,

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyspark/context.py in _ensure_initialized(cls, instance, gateway, conf)
    330                         " created by %s at %s:%s "
    331                         % (currentAppName, currentMaster,
--> 332                             callsite.function, callsite.file, callsite.linenum))
    333                 else:
    334                     SparkContext._active_spark_context = instance

ValueError: Cannot run multiple SparkContexts at once; existing SparkContext(app=pyspark-shell, master=local[*]) created by __init__ at <ipython-input-7-edf43bdce70a>:33
```

- **imports**

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
```

- I tried this alternative approach, which fails too:

```
spark = SparkSession(sc).builder.appName("Detecting-Malicious-URL App").getOrCreate()
```

This is throwing another error as follows:

```
NameError: name 'SparkSession' is not defined
```

Comment: Try this:  from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

Answer (score 8):

Try this -

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Detecting-Malicious-URL App").getOrCreate()
```

Before spark 2.0 we had to create a SparkConf and SparkContext to interact with Spark.

Whereas in Spark 2.0 SparkSession is the entry point to Spark SQL. Now we don't need to create SparkConf, SparkContext or SQLContext, as they’re encapsulated within the SparkSession.

Please refer this blog for more details : [How to use SparkSession in Apache Spark 2.0](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/08/15/how-to-use-sparksession-in-apache-spark-2-0.html)

Comment: If  your issue is resolved then accept the best suitable answer and close this thread.

Comment: i got this error 'bytes' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Answer (score 0):

spark context is used to connect to the cluster through a resource manager.
sparkConf is required to create the spark context object, which stores configuration parameter like appName (to identify your spark driver), application, number of core and memory size of executor running on worker node. To use APIs of Sql, Hive, Streaming separate contexts need to be created.

While as for SparkSession provides a single point of entry to interact with underlying Spark functionality and allows programming Spark with Dataframes and API's. It don't need to create a separate session to use Sql, Hive etc.

To create a SparkSession you might use the following builder

> SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("Detecting-Malicious-URL
>   App")     .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value")

To overcome this error

> "NameError: name 'SparkSession' is not defined"

you might need to use a package calling such as

> "from pyspark.sql import SparkSession"

pyspark.sql supports spark session which is used to create data frames or register data frames as tables etc.

And the above error

> (ValueError: Cannot run multiple SparkContexts at once; existing
>   SparkContext(app=pyspark-shell, master=local[*]) created by **init**
>   at :33 )

you specified this might be helpful- [ValueError: Cannot run multiple SparkContexts at once in spark with pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46351951/valueerror-cannot-run-multiple-sparkcontexts-at-once-in-spark-with-pyspark)

Comment: Yes, I have used pyspark instead of pyspark.sql... Thanks

Comment: If this is helpful and able to resolve the issue, please select one of the best suitable answer.

Answer (score 0):

Faced Similar problem on Win 10 Solved by following Way:-
go to the Conda prompt and run the following command:-
# Install OpenJDK 11

> conda install openjdk

Then run the:-

> SparkSession.builder.appName('...').getOrCreate()